# what is the font used by the ACM paper 'in acmtrans2.cls`

Tags: acm

does anyone know what is the font used by the new ACM paper `acmtrans2m.cls` template/class? I want to reuse the acmart class for my synopsis with acmtrans2M.cls's font type and I really like this acmtrans2m.cls font over `acmart` font.

https://ijngc.perpetualinnovation.net/index.php/ijngc/pf

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: there is no `acmtrans2.cls` in texlive please give a link to the file, if you have an example using that, pdflatex will always report all fonts in used at the end of the log.

Comment: it can be downloaded from https://ijngc.perpetualinnovation.net/index.php/ijngc/pf

Comment: The class doesn't load any font packages; the examples use the default Computer Modern.

Comment: please edit the question not put it in a comment., That is `acmtrans2M.cls` not `acmtrans2.cls` and it is not new it is positively ancient:  it declares `\ProvidesClass{acmtrans2m} [1996/07/03 Transactions class based on <23 April 96>]`  1996!!!! the acm.org website has far newer templates (with different names)

Comment: I know it's old ; publishers are telling the author to run with that code. can we get the closest look and feel of `acmtrans2M` using `acmart `

Comment: if you know it's old, why did you write "_new_" in the question?  I used M to highlight the spelling error but it is `m` and you only fixed it in one place, you still have the wrong name in the title and later in the question. But as campa says the class does nothing with fonts so you just get the default latex font.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. You mention `acmtrans2m.cls`, `acmtrans2M.cls` and `acmtrans2.cls` Can you clarify which one you actually mean?

Comment: The `acmtrans2m` class uses the default Computer Modern fonts. Notwithstanding that the linked page claims that “IJNGC conforms to the ACM journal format”, this is untrue, because since some years ACM has switched to Libertine fonts and of course a querter-of-a-century old document class is unlikely to conform.

Comment: @egreg I submitted the latex sources there and they accepted then they charged me back for the conversion eg. downgrade to their `acmtrans2m` so I thought if I could just convert the fonts to `acmtrans2m` it would work. could you please suggest the conversion commands from  Libertine  to Computer Modern fonts?